# Difference between DBus and other Interprocess Communications method

Tags: c++, c, linux, ubuntu, dbus

When i studied about Linux interprocess Communications, i have known there were some method as: pipe, message queue, socket, signal, shared memory, semaphore and there is no method named Dbus.

But today, when i research about Dbus, i read that: "D-Bus is a system for interprocess communication (IPC)" (See that link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-Bus)

So my question is: 
What is the different between DBus and other IPC methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A one to one ipc method has a large group of cooperating process can cause a dense mesh. But in case of a Dbus each process can connect to any number of process provided with a grant access. On a common single shared channel a user can connect with his own session or a new session without interfering the session of other user. This greatly increase the performance

Refer the link

https://blogs.gnome.org/abustany/2010/05/20/ipc-performance-the-return-of-the-report/

This shows the comparison of the DBus performance against a custom IPC system. You get a better understanding of the performance of the Dbus

Comment: Well, there are other (classic) IPC that aren't strictly one to one, e.g. shared memory.

Comment: why Dbus is not known as a ipc method?

Comment: @Murali: but why in many documents, all of IPC methods does not contain DBUS?
Example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication

Comment: @Viet DBUS utilize IPC mechanisms, but don't implement IPC themselves.

Answer (score 5):

There is no technical, but historical difference.

D-Bus didn't used to be a Linux (i.e. kernel) IPC, but an additional middleware IPC. But in the course of introduction of [`systemd`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd), D-Bus became for several Linux distributions a part of the basic system.

Comment: Thanks. By "middileware IPC" do you mean D-Bus is at a higher IPC level  than those https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication? Could you also enumerate some other "middileware IPC"  methods?

Comment: This is not quite true. While systemd does use D-Bus extensively, D-Bus was already essentially a required component of most free desktop distributions well before systemd was written. They are separate projects.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't see what part do you object. The fact that D-Bus was used before systemd, doesn't make it a (kernel) IPC. This is similar to RPC. You will find lots of projects that use RPC. However, the most RPC implementations used to rely on sockets (that in turn is frequently a kernel IPC).

Comment: @Matthias I think the objection is in regards to your characterization of its implied relation to `systemd`, and not about it being kernel-based. The inclusion of D-Bus in popular distros was not dependent upon something to do with `systemd`. Not sure if intended, but implying that it is somehow related to `systemd` feels like it is appealing to some's dissatisfaction with that software and thus intending to cast that onto D-Bus in some way.